# iOS iCarousel image offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, icarousel

Good afternoon. ICarusel I use in my application. I have an image that is loaded as image view. Images are placed exactly in the center. Please tell me how do I move the image up to only 50 pixels in it without moving the rest of the content?

The method for creating views like that:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    NSString *docDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Caches"];
    NSDictionary *myDic =[magazinesInfo objectAtIndex:index];

    //Resize image
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@_img.png",docDir,[myDic objectForKey:@"title"]]] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(375,510)];

    UIImageView *romb = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 118, 135)];
    UIImageView *faceImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,768,1004)];
    UIImage *dwImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
    UIImage *readImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"read_button.png"];
    UIImage *deleteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"delete_button.png"];

    if(view ==nil)
    {

        UIButton *myDownloadButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        [myDownloadButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [myDownloadButton setHidden:YES];


        romb.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"romb.png"];

        view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004)];
        [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        view = faceImage;
        faceImage.image = nil;

        ((UIImageView *)view).image = nil;
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;


        //Magazine number
        myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(345, 85, 75, 29)];
        myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [myLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:36.0f]];
        myLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        myLabel.tag = 1;

        //Magazine name
        nameMag = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-65, 450, 100, 100)];
        nameMag.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        nameMag.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [nameMag setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:30.0f]];
        nameMag.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        nameMag.tag = 3;

        //Date
        dateMag = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-67, 500, 500, 30)];
        dateMag.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        dateMag.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [dateMag setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:20.0f]];
        dateMag.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        dateMag.tag = 4;


        //Download button
        downloadButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(350, 700, 128, 37)];
        [downloadButton setBackgroundImage:dwImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [downloadButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressDownload:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        downloadButton.tag = 5;

        //Read button
        readButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 750, 128, 37)];
        [readButton setBackgroundImage:readImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [readButton addTarget:self action:@selector(readMag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        readButton.hidden=YES;
        readButton.tag = 8;

        //Delete button
        deleteButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(400, 750, 128, 37)];
        [deleteButton setBackgroundImage:deleteImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteMag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        deleteButton.hidden=YES;
        deleteButton.tag = 9;

        //Progress bar
        downloadProgress  = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 800, 127, 8)];
        downloadPrecent = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 800, 8, 8)];
        downloadPrecent.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [downloadPrecent setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:20.0f]];
        dateMag.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        downloadProgress.tag = 6;
        downloadPrecent.tag = 7;
        downloadProgress.hidden = YES;
        downloadPrecent.hidden = YES;



        //Add image subview
        [view addSubview:romb];

        //Label subview
        [view addSubview:myLabel];
        [view addSubview:nameMag];
        [view addSubview:dateMag];

        //Progressbar subview
        [view addSubview:downloadProgress];
        [view addSubview:downloadPrecent];

        //Buttons subview
        [view addSubview:downloadButton];
        [view addSubview:readButton];
        [view addSubview:deleteButton];
        [view addSubview:myDownloadButton];



    }

    else
    {

        romb.image = (UIImage*)[romb viewWithTag:3];
        ((UIImageView *)faceImage).image = (UIImage*)[view viewWithTag:2];


        myLabel = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:1];
        nameMag = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:3];
        dateMag = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:4];


        downloadProgress = (UIProgressView *) [view viewWithTag:6];
        downloadPrecent = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:7];



        downloadButton  = (UIButton *) [view viewWithTag:5];
        readButton  = (UIButton *) [view viewWithTag:8];
        deleteButton = (UIButton*) [view viewWithTag:9];



    }


        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSLog(@"index is: %i",index);
        NSLog(@"current item index %i",[self.carousel currentItemIndex]);
        NSLog(@"%hhd",[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@_mag.pdf",docDir,[myDic objectForKey:@"title"]]]);

        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@_mag.pdf",docDir,[myDic objectForKey:@"title"]]] == YES && (index == [self.carousel currentItemIndex]))
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",[[view subviews] objectAtIndex:9]);
            [[[view subviews] objectAtIndex:9] setHidden:NO];
            readButton.hidden = NO;
            deleteButton.hidden = NO;
            downloadButton.hidden = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            [[[view subviews] objectAtIndex:9] setHidden:YES];
            readButton.hidden = YES;
            deleteButton.hidden = YES;
            downloadButton.hidden = NO;

        }

    ((UIImageView *)view).image = img;
    myLabel.text = [myDic objectForKey:@"title"];
    dateMag.text = [myDic objectForKey:@"date"];
    romb.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"romb.png"];


    return view;
}
```

Now it looks like this (do not worry, it's still developing :))
http://files.mail.ru/B2B41BA915624173B646184D4283D9F9?t=1

Answer (score 0):

Use the contentOffset property to shift the carousel contents relative to the carousel view without changing their perspective.

You can use the viewpointOffset propert instead if you want it to look like the perspective has changed (i.e as if you are looking at the carousel from below).

Comment: Changing of contentOffset or viewPointOffset do not lead to the result. Of all that is on the View shifted by the specified value. I just need to move the image, and the blue shapes to leave in place. (I gave a link to what the application looks like now)